# php-mobile-detect

Tags: jquery, css

i've just come across php-mobile-detect and i want to add it to my site. so far my current code is.

```
<?php
include("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
?>
<?php if($detect->isiPad()) {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">';     
}
?>
```

This is working fine when i go on the ipad it shows the css, now what i want todo is add all iPhones, android devices, blackberry's etc to one css and any other desktop version to another css?

I know i'm close but i can't quite get there.

Comment: Is this the detecting code you're using? http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/  If not, could you please link to what source you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work your you:

```
<?php
include("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    echo 'mobile';
}else{
    echo 'desktop';
}
?>
```